# Can't get web scraper to loop through list of ID numbers from CSV file and send keys to website to search

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a CSV file that contains a list of ID numbers that I want to then use to search within a search bar on a website using ChromeDrive and selenium using python. I would like to loop through this list and search each number and web scrape the data from the website. I would like the web scraper to use a list of numbers that I update daily. Any thoughts? I am using `driver.find_element_by_id`,  `driver.find_element_by_xpath` and `.send_keys()` for most of my web scraping.

I was able to use one ID number as an example to web scrape the website using selenium

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
from PIL import Image
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv

#Open Browser and go to website log-in page
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1440,1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('website')

#locating username and password elements
driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    
driver.find_element_by_id("okta-signin-password")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("okta-signin-password")
    
#logging in with keys
username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")
    
driver.find_element_by_id("signin-button").click()
    
with open('/Users/work/Desktop/IDTestNumbers.csv') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)

# here is where I am lost. not sure how to grab the list and loop through them to send the keys to the website search bar and scrape the data from there*

driver.find_element_by_id('phSearchInput').send_keys("ID-00091310")
driver.find_element_by_id("phSearchButton").click()
```

Comment: can you please add the website URL along with some samples of the data you're reading from the CSV file, that'll make your question complete and reproducible so that others can help.